# How should i make recursion function in java?

Tags: java, arrays, function, recursion, arraylist

I am trying to make a program which get all the prerequisites of the course i also need to get the prerequisites of the prerequisites until i get a Course which does not have any prerequisites and store all of them in a array.
so far i try this code:

```
public class MainFunctions {

public static int[] getPrerequisites(int value){
    ArrayList<Integer> obj = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Datasource ds=new Datasource(); 
            try{
            ds.connect();
            java.sql.Statement s=ds.createStatement();
             int[] arr1 = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(obj.toArray(new Integer[obj.size()]));
               ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("Select prerequisites_course_id from common_course_prerequisites where course_id="+value);         
               while(rs.next()){
              int a =rs.getInt(1);
                   boolean contains = IntStream.of(arr1).anyMatch(x -> x == a);
                   if(contains==false){
                    obj.add(rs.getInt(1));
                    MainFunctions.getPrerequisites(rs.getInt(1));                      
                   }
             }
                ds.dropConnection();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }           
        int[] arr = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(obj.toArray(new Integer[obj.size()]));   
        System.out.println(obj);
        return arr;
         //boolean contains = IntStream.of(arr).anyMatch(x -> x == a);   
    }
}
```

this is the test data of courses and prerequisites of them [image: my DB table]

Comment: If the nesting could be really deep, you have to use a recursive method. That's a method that calls itself. Try to look up about that for more info.

Comment: yes my nesting is really deep but as i am newbie in java so i cant figure out what i should use so i can that deep

Comment: Send the test data , the question

Comment: yes i have edit the question so u can see my db table data @Echo

Comment: if i can suggest something, try to write recursive sql query. this will make your solution more efficient and you will achieve this in single query.